# Matrix multiplication in GSL-GNU

Tags: c++, c, matrix, matrix-multiplication, gsl

Kindly tell me the function of matrix multiplication in GSL library. I have searched a lot but I am not be able to fine it. If any one know about that function kindly answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you'll want to use the `gemm` family of functions, such as [`gsl_blas_sgemm()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Level-3-GSL-BLAS-Interface.html).  Just set the scalars to one and the added matrix to zero.  An example is [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gslref/BLASExamples.html).